# How do I fix my Keylogger code to produce an output?

Tags: python, keylogger, pynput

I'm trying to make a keylogger script on python 2.7, followed some instructions on how to do so but mine didn't produce any output when I try running it and pressed some keys. Any idea how to fix it or what am I missing on my code? :/

Here's the code:

```
import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener


def on_press(key):
    print("(0) pressed".format(key))


def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        return False


with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Python 2.* isn’t supported anymore. If you’re not working in critical infrastructure, you should change to at least Python 3.7.